Calling GITLAB job from python API call
I have a Python function that triggers a GitLab job using two variables: tag and release. The function works as expected when using a pipeline trigger token, but when I switch to a private token, I encounter the following error:
Response Status Code: 400
Response Body: {"error":"variables is invalid"}

here is my python code:
import requests
import json

# Function to trigger GitLab pipeline
def trigger_gitlab_pipeline(project_id, tag, release, branch, private_token):
    url = f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/pipeline"
    
    headers = {
        'PRIVATE-TOKEN': private_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    # Data payload, ensuring release is a string
    data = {
        'ref': branch,
        'variables': {
            'TAG_NAME': tag,
            'RELEASE_NUM': release
        }
    }
    
    print("Request Data:", json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    
    # Send the request
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    
    # Output the result
    print("Response Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response Body:", response.text)

# Example usage
project_id = <project_id>
tag = "AGT_v1.2.0-b25_and_AWB_v1.2.0-b08"
release = 88  # This will be converted to string
branch = "pipe_modi"
private_token = <token>

trigger_gitlab_pipeline(project_id, tag, release, branch, private_token)

Am i overlooking something or anything wrong in how i make the call?

according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline, you must send a array of hashes for "variables" (https://docs.gitlab.com/17.5/ee/api/rest/index.html#array-of-hashes) matching this structure:
[
    { 'key': 'UPLOAD_TO_S3', 'variable_type': 'file', 'value': 'true' }, 
    { 'key': 'TEST', 'value': 'test variable' }
]

then, please try this:
# Data payload, with variables as a list of dictionaries
data = {
    'id': project_id,
    'ref': branch,
    'variables': [
        {'key': 'TAG_NAME', 'value': tag},
        {'key': 'RELEASE_NUM', 'value': release}
    ]
}

